# cause of error: 'QSqlDatabase::addDatabase' cannot appear in a constant-expression

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, qt

im making a sql connection in qt qnd i have this error after running my codes :
this is part of my header file:

```
private:
Ui::School *ui;
QString user;
QString pass;
QSqlDatabase db1 =QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
```

and this is part of my cpp file:

```
void School :: set_db() {
db1.setDatabaseName( "school.db");
bool isOpen = db1.open() ;

}
```

then i got this error:

```
 error: 'QSqlDatabase::addDatabase' cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

and i dont know what should i do ?

Comment: At the very least (without knowing the details of `QSqlDataBase::addDatabase`) you would need C++11 compiler support for this initialization to work.

Comment: The easy way out is to call db1 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(...) in the constructor (or initializer list)